# Как правильно составить запрос?

Tags: doctrine, symfony2

Есть теги на сайте. Они реализованы через таблицу связи (post_id, tag_id).
Нужно достать все новости с максимально повторяющимися тегами.

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
SELECT Post.id, Post.title
        FROM news_post Post
        INNER JOIN `news_post_tags` Post_Tags
        ON  Post.id = Post_Tags.post_id
        WHERE Post_Tags.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 
        GROUP BY Post_Tags.post_id 
        ORDER BY COUNT( Post_Tags.tag_id ) DESC
```

Он отлично работает, и теперь его нужно написать с помощью доктрины.

Я начал писать:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT Post "
                . "FROM IlichNewsBundle:Post Post "
                . "INNER JOIN Post.tags Tags "
            )
            ->setFirstResult(0)->setMaxResults(50)->getResult();
```

Доктрина генерирует что-то такое:

```
SELECT 
  n0_.id AS id0, 
  n0_.slug AS slug1, 
  ... 
FROM 
  news_post n0_ 
  INNER JOIN news_post_tags n2_ ON n0_.id = n2_.post_id 
  INNER JOIN Tag t1_ ON t1_.id = n2_.tag_id 
LIMIT 
  50 OFFSET 0
```

Так вот, мне нужно получить доступ к таблице:

```
INNER JOIN news_post_tags n2_ ON n0_.id = n2_.post_id
```

То есть сделать что-то такое:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT Post "
                . "FROM IlichNewsBundle:Post Post "
                . "INNER JOIN Post.tags Tags "
        GROUP BY n0_.post_id 
        ORDER BY COUNT( n0_.tag_id ) DESC;
            )
            ->setFirstResult(0)->setMaxResults(50)->getResult();
```

Как можно задать алиас вот этой таблице - `news_post_tags`?

Answer (score 1):

Запросы не объединяются через INNER JOIN. Через INNER JOIN объединяются таблицы в запросах. Чтобы объединить запросы, достаточно написать их друг за другом в одном скрипте.

Comment: @kot197676, это доктрина, то, что вы видите, - это не SQL. Автор нигде и не говорит, что ему нужно объединить запросы, и уж точно они не объединяются последовательным написанием.

Comment: Сорри, плохо прочитал вопрос, сейчас 24 часа, подумаю и отвечу.

Comment: прочитайте внимательно Ваш код можно сократит до 4 строк-http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html